# How does windows authentication work at a socket level

Tags: windows, windows-authentication

I am frequently having issues understanding windows authentication and it occurs to me that is is because I don't understand the protocol.

I'm curious how things like pass through authentication work.
What sockets are created to validate a user.
What kind of data is exchanged.
Are there any open source c#/java/scala implementations which would be a good reference.

Comment: if you are refering to IIS windows passthrough authentication, it uses NTLM protocols for auth. it doesn't occur at the sockets layer.

Comment: I suppose I was looking for the distinctions.  Mostly I'm curious about AD domains, NTLM protocol, how you are prompted for file shares, and web shares.

Comment: In Active Directory, [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) is the primary authentication protocol, with NTLM being a leftover from Windows NT 4 days.

Comment: @grawity Your answer was good, why did you delete it? I would have upvoted it.